# Python: Strange behaviour of raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

The code below provides an unexpected answer when I use raw_input. Can anyone explain me what is happening and how to solve it?

```
import numpy as np
response = raw_input("What is your move? ")
response=np.array(response)
changingPositions=np.flatnonzero(response)
print changingPositions

response=np.array([0,1,0])
changingPositions=np.flatnonzero(response)
print changingPositions
```

The execution is:

```
What is your move? [0,1,0]
[0]
[1]
```

The expected answer is

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, in fact `np.flatnonzero(np.array('adfsgh'))` produces `array([0])` too. So just make a list of ints:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: response = raw_input("What is your move? ")
What is your move? 0,1,0

In [3]: positions = np.array(map(int, response.split(',')))

In [4]: changing_positions = np.flatnonzero(positions)

In [5]: changing_positions
Out[5]: array([1])
```

Answer (score 1):

response is a **string** element. But you want an **list**.

so you need to parse the user input to a list. You should use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`, which parses the user input, or use `eval(raw_input())` (`eval()` parses a string to an element...

But I suggest to surround this function with try..except, to check if the user input is valid, and also loop if input is still invalid:

```
import numpy as np

isValid = False

while !isValid:
    try:
        response = input("What is your move? ")
        isValid = True
    except:
        print("Input is not valid!!")

response=np.array(response)
changingPositions=np.flatnonzero(response)
print changingPositions

response=np.array([0,1,0])
changingPositions=np.flatnonzero(response)
print changingPositions
```